# Is it possible, using jquery, to target all elements of a specific class within the parent div of the button that calls the event?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

Ideally I would like to be able to make the event target all p.hiddeninput, which do not also have the specific ("." + this.id + "Y") class, within the parent div of the radio buttons. I have tried using the .parent() selector without any success.

I have a situation where I need to set up 5 radio buttons, 4 of which need to display a specific hidden input when they are clicked. Both the price table and supplement radio buttons need to open the same input. Any previously open inputs need to also hide when this occurs. Currently I have html that looks like this,

```
<input value="auto" type="radio" class="oneofmany" name="buypricebyradio" id="buypricebyradiomarkdown">Markdown</input>
<input value="pricetable" type="radio" class="oneofmany" name="buypricebyradio" id="buypricebyradiopricetable">Price table</input>
<input value="fromsupplement" type="radio" class="oneofmany" name="buypricebyradio" id="buypricebyradiofromsupplement">From supplement</input>
<input value="discount" type="radio" class="oneofmany" name="buypricebyradio" id="buypricebyradiodiscount">Discount</input>
<input value="noprice" type="radio" class="oneofmany" name="buypricebyradio" id="buypricebyradionoprice">No price</input>


<p style="display:none" class="buypricebyradiopricetableY buypricebyradiofromsupplementY hiddeninput"><label for="buyingpricetable">Buying price table:</label><input class="medium include search" id="buyingpricetablesearch"></input></p>
<p style="display:none" class="buypricebyradiomarkdownY hiddeninput"><label for="markdownstyle">Mark down style:</label><input class="medium include search" id="markdownstylesearch"></input></p>
<p style="display:none" class="buypricebyradiodiscountY hiddeninput"><label for="buydiscountstyle">Discount style:</label><input class="medium include search" id="buydiscountstylesearch"></input></p>
```

With a jscript command of

```
$('.oneofmany').click(function(){     
      $("p.hiddeninput").not("." + this.id + "Y").hide();   
      $('.' + this.id + "Y").show();
});
```

This works just fine for one set of radio buttons and inputs. However I need to have multiple sets, and in this situation, when a radio button is clicked in one set of inputs, it closes all the inputs in the other sections as well.

Is it possible to target an event like this, and if not can anyone suggest a solution to this problem? Thank you for your time.

Comment: jQuery's documentation is quite comprehensive: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: update your fiddle please here http://jsfiddle.net/3sHMj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> target all elements of a specific class within the parent div of the button that calls the event?

```
$(this).parent('div').find('.specific-class')
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution I was looking for with the targetting. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You meant like this?

```
$('.oneofmany').click(function(){     
      $(this).parent('div').find("p.hiddeninput").not("." + this.id + "Y").hide();   
      $(this).parent('div').find('.' + this.id + "Y").show();
});
```

Comment: I did indeed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case is best to just write:

```
$('.oneofmany').click(function(){
  var targetId = this.id + 'Y';

  $(this).parent('div').find("p.hiddeninput").each(function(){
    $(this).toggle(this.id == targetId);
  });
});
```

`$(this).parent('div')` will traverse to element's parents until it finds a "div". Then `.find('p.hiddeninput')` will find all the hiddeninput diffs. And after this you will toggle the visibility of each of them depending on their ids.

Is more preferment that way then manually select all elements which have to be shown and hide the rest.

p.s. the other way is just to do:

```
$('.oneofmany').click(function(){
 $(this).parent('div').find("p.hiddeninput").hide();
 $('#' + this.id + 'Y').show();
});
```

Where you will hide all elements, and then just show the unique id one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and explaining the selectors. I'll look into using them as you describe in future